# Why does recursive fibonacci work?

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

I was looking at the following code:

```
function _fibonacci(n) {
   if (n < 2){
     return 1;
   }else{
     return _fibonacci(n-2) + _fibonacci(n-1);
   }
} 
console.log(_fibonacci(5))
```

I understand HOW this works, but I do not understand WHY this works. Can someone explain to me why this works?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about it? And how can you understand how it works but not why it works?

Comment: Why it gives you the correct result you mean?

Comment: It works because the recursive behavior is broken when 1 is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple, the fibonacci answer for both location 0 and 1 are both 1 (the sequence looks like 1 1 2 3 5 8 etc...) so when it enters the function with n being 0 or 1 (which can happen for both the n-2 recursive call and the n-1 recursive call), the result is 1. For all other values it just keeps adding the numbers.

(Note that the values for the first 2 in the sequence can be 0 1 or 1 1, depending on your definition of the sequence. For this one it's apparently assumed the first 2 are both 1.)

Comment: Actually this implementation assumes that anything below 2 is 1, so if I were to say `_fibonacci(-1)` or `_fibonacci(0)` I would still get 1. Seems like an incorrect implementation.

Comment: Well yeah you could argue that you need sanitizing of the input so it is higher than 0, but I assume that's just left out to not overcomplicate things. Many implementations actually do consider a 0 to be the first number of the sequence so then you can just return 0 for n=0 and only need to throw an exception for values below 0.